# JHipster with React - How to create a unique routing file to manage all components in the module folder?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, jhipster

When I generate a new application with one entity, I have this structure:

```
webapp
├── app                                        
│   └── entities
│       ├── foo                           - CRUD front-end for the Foo entity
│       │   ├── foo-delete-dialog.tsx     - Delete dialog component
│       │   ├── foo-detail.tsx            - Detail page component
│       │   ├── foo-dialog.tsx            - Creation dialog component
│       │   ├── foo.reducer.ts            - Foo entity reducer
│       │   ├── foo.tsx                   - Entity main component
│       │   └── index.tsx                 - Entity main routes
│       └── index.tsx                     - Entities routes
```

To adapt this code to my needs, I copy and paste the entire folder `app/entities/foo` to `app/modules/foo` because I want to avoid conflicts while manipulating the foo entity with the generator. I fixed all import errors.
However, the `app/modules/foo/index.tsx` file does not work the same way it works in `app/entities/foo/index.tsx`. React-router not rendering components on route change. Please how to achieve this in a module folder the same way it's done in the entity folder?

Comment: It would be helpful to see a sample of the code that is not working, and what you have tried

Comment: @JonRuddell I updated my problem. I think it is more understandable that way.